# What is Moonlight technically?

Tags: moonlight

There is surprisingly little information on the internet regarding what Moonlight is exactly from a technical point of view. Is it correct to understand it as Mono-based CoreCLR + base libraries (the same .dlls as Silverlight has as part of the plugin itself)?

Does this mean that if I have Silverlight 3.0 application and I reference base library, plus develop my own Silverlight libraries, this application will work the same in Moonlight 3.0 (when available), except for bugs, etc., of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your Silverlight applications should run with moonlight (modulo bugs, yeah).
From [moonlight-project.com](http://www.moonlight-project.com/):

> Moonlight is an open source
>   implementation of Silverlight,
>   primarily for Linux and other Unix/X11
>   based operating systems. In September
>   of 2007, Microsoft and Novell
>   announced a technical collaboration
>   that includes access to Microsoft's
>   test suites for Silverlight and the
>   distribution of a Media Pack for Linux
>   users that will contain licensed media
>   codecs for video and audio.

Moonlight 2.0 should be out soon and there's already work underway in supporting Silverlight 3.0 features.

Comment: Meanwhile Microsoft announce Silverlight 4.0 with its Windows-only COM automation. Is Moonlight scuppered already?

Comment: From what I've heard, it's not a big leap forward (implementation wise) from 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

That is the theory. Time will show if it works out.